# Zumero sync fails with status code 244

Tags: zumero

I've a customer that yesterday has migrated some servers except the ones hosting Zumero's IIS and the database, but in order to complete the operations had to pull down all the sites. Now his technician aren't able to complete a correct synchronization: every request terminates with status code 244 and a server response totaling 1.6MB

Trying to understand if it was a site general problem, I've took my test tablet installed his app, and starting from scratch the first sync goes out well, delivering me the whole database (approx. 3,5MB): after this first sync all subsequent synchronization works well too, giving a response size of 0 bytes (as it has to be) and a 200 status code.

I'd like to understand what's going on, before suggesting him to erase all the tablet's database, because I don't know if they have some unsent data, but they surely worked during the migration period, so probably many of them have unsent data.

Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

ZSS server version number is 1.4.1.2030

Comment: Have you tried upgrading ZSS server to the current version? `2.1.1.2959`

Comment: I assume the HTTP status code 244 is observed in the server logs somewhere. What error (if any) is being returned by the sync call on the client side?

Comment: Was the SQL Database rolled back, or backed up/restored during this time? *i.e.* were there successful syncs, followed by a rollback, which the clients are aware of but the server has now "forgotten"?

Comment: The upgrade was not done because the customer has already changed 2 times his external IP address; dued to some issues during the initial startup that took some brain power to remove, he has opted to not upgrade the server as the license of the new version is bounded to the IP address.

Comment: The status code is observed inside the zumero.log table, and there aren't any other kind of warning or error entries in Windows Event registers. I'm not aware of any error, because as per explicit request the app does't show error messages, there's only a warning on the last sync date showed in the status bar. Unfortunately the log files has been cleared along with all the other data (db included), because the customer couldn't wait anymore.

Comment: SQL Server has not been rolled back, backed up or restored; the customer had to migrate some old Windows 2003 servers because of the end of support, but the machine with SQL Server and the other one with IIS were already Windows Server2008, so they remain untouched.

Comment: @RodolfoRedolfi It's worth noting that the v2 licenses are bound to hostname/port, not (necessarily) IP address. A hostname that was updated and maintained when the IP address changed would work fine, unless the clients were synching by IP address. Even in that case, a replacement activation key could be issued, so the license would now work with the new address. For obvious reasons (license consistency and no need to update client config), the hostname approach is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Well i hope there was no customer data lost, but otherwise i am glad that the customer is back up and running. It is unfortunate that the client-side error log has been cleared and we've missed the opportunity to observe the errors.

For future reference, though: A status code of 244 can happen during normal use for various reasons, and its presence in the zumero.log table does not indicate a failure. The concerning symptom, rather, was that clients were unable to complete a sync. In order to diagnose the problem, the Zumero team would need to see the error messages being returned by the client. From there, more information might be needed as well, in which case it may be necessary to contact Zumero support directly.

Comment: The data loss was minimal, as it was reduced to only one business day (Friday, when they migrated the servers). He decided to reset the tablet's database as soon as possible in order to not loose other work time. I've modfied the app in order to be able to send, in response to a request coming from the central database, the log files and the database itself through a separated web service. Should happen again I'll be able to provide them to Zumero support.